# sequelize.query() is not a FUNCTION

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I am new to sequelize. I am trying to use row query, but I'm getting an error.

Code:

```
const sequelize = require('sequelize');

sequelize.query("SELECT * from users").then(results => {
      console.log(results);
   })
```

Error while calling this API:

```
(node:2380) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: sequelize.query is not a function
    at Promise (C:\NodejsProject\mars\app\schedule\models\schedule.js:247:17)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It was my mistake .Database configuration was in another file so i imported that file and now everthing is working.

Comment: Yes. after importing database configure file, it will work perfectly. I face same issue and get resolve after importing database config file

Answer (score 27):

> You can't use `sequelize` directly from `require('sequelize');` ,
>   first we need to create instance of that , and instance will be
>   created from DB details , so  `sequelize` can know on which platform ,
>   which DB it has to run the query

Here is the basic snippet , just for a idea :

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'|'sqlite'|'postgres'|'mssql',

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite',

  // http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html#operators
  operatorsAliases: false
});

sequelize.query("SELECT * from users").then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

For more detail : **[DO READ](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/)**

Answer (score 11):

If you are running your db config in external file AND want and extra layer to protect from SQL injection
./database/dbs.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
const db = {}
const sequelize = new Sequelize('dbname', 
                                'username', 
                                'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  logging: console.log,
  freezeTableName: true,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  }
})

db.sequelize = sequelize
db.Sequelize = Sequelize

module.exports = db
```

then in the file you want to use:

```
const db        = require('../database/db')
...
    const newDbName = 'myNewDb'
    db.sequelize.query(`CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${newDbName} `, {
        type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.CREATE
    }).then( () => {
        res.send('ok done creating ' + req.body.newDbName).end()
    }).catch( err => {
        res.status(500).send('Err executing command ' + err).end()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

`dbConnect.js`:

```js
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');<br/>

const con =  new Sequelize.Sequelize(<br/>
  'db',
  "user",
  "password",
  {
    host: "localhost",
    dialect: "mysql",
    operatorsAliases: false,
    pool: {
      max: 5,
      min: 0,
      acquire: 30000,
      idle: 10000
    },
  },
);

con.query("SELECT 1", (err, rows) => {
    console.log(rows)
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(err)
}).then(function (result){
    console.log("inventory")
    console.log(result)
});

module.exports = con;
```

```
// import
let con = require("../common/dbConnect")

// use in function
const [results, metadata] = await con.query(
  "SELECT * FROM officer JOIN user ON officer.UserID = user.UserID"
);
console.log(JSON.stringify(results, null, 2));
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.